# How do I turn the key combination, ctrl+shift+9, into the string "ctrl+(" in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

I was using `event.unicode` for this task previously. If I hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>, then the event for the key down has a unicode attribute of '('. And if I hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>, then the event for the key down has a unicode attribute of '(', and the keyboard also sends a keydown for an alt key, so that I know one was pressed.

If, however, I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>, then `event.unicode == u''`. How do I get `u'('` back from that?

(similarly, for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, I get `'\x01'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, all keystrokes you revieve while <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is pressed are "altered", since this was the whole intention for creating the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key: Sending control instructions instead of simply text.

If you look at a [ASCII table](http://www.unix-manuals.com/refs/misc/ascii-table.html), you'll see e.g. how <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> maps to the control character `BS (Backspace)`.

So, no chance for you here to recieve `'('` on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> simply through `KEY_DOWN`.

---

You'll have to go through `pygame.key.get_pressed()` to check for pressed keys.

```
    if e.type == KEYDOWN:
        k = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        m = pygame.key.get_mods()
        if m & KMOD_SHIFT and k[K_9]:
            if m & KMOD_CTRL:
                print "controlled yay!"
            else:
                print "yay!"
```

Comment: Argh, that's unfortunate. Solution won't work, but I'm glad to have some verification that I'm facing the impossible here. :(

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an easier way to do this, but you could get the state of all the keys on the keyboard using `pygame.key.get_pressed()` and then check to see if the two keys pressed are the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and <kbd>9</kbd> keys. then you could manually return the string <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd> instead of getting that from a function. Not sure if there is a really elegant way to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

To check for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

```
`for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LCTRL]:
            if event.key == pygame.K_t:`
```